# Sum instances of different values and total their price

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have a table called 2013_orders

The columns I am dealing with are "ordate", "item", and "price". None of these are the primary key of the table.

I have a date select form to select a date range. The tags are "from_date" and "to_date".

In the item column is the part numbers of the part numbers ordered. This column is not restricted to unique values since it'll have multiple instances of the same part numbers.

The ordate column is the order date. This is what I need the date range to look at.

The price column is the price of each part number (item) ordered.

What I need is to have the instances of each part number in the selected date range totaled into one sum for that part number. Then I need The total dollar amount (price) totaled for that part number for that selected date range.

It should  display:

```
Part Number                Total                  Total Price

555111                       28                     150.23
116000                       55                      67.88
770-A                       151                     980.55
```

.....and so forth

[table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Nmkw.jpg)

I'm making this post from home and the code variations I have tried are at work, so I don't have an  example of an attempt handy. Maybe that's for the best LOL!

Comment: post your table schema here.

Comment: As an aside, take a look at partitioning

Answer (score 5):

This seems like a simple `GROUP BY` operation:

```sql
SELECT item, COUNT(*) AS Total, SUM(Price) AS Total_Price
FROM mytable
GROUP By item
```

Comment: I do believe I tried that code format. The totals were correct, but it kept repeating part numbers. I'll check again. Would the date range code go right after **GROUP By Item**? The line I am using is **WHERE ordate BETWEEN '#from_date#' AND '#to_date# **